# ASPNETBOILERPLATE .Net Core template - Existing database code sample request

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, aspnetboilerplate

We are looking to implement the ABP template at our enterprise. We have existing app DB's that cannot be used with code-first EF. The enterprise will not permit use of code-first method. So we need to use db-first method.
If there is someone who has implemented ABP with an existing DB and SPs. Can you please share some code snippets of all the changes you made to the template that enabled db-first use. 
All responses are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO! To better understand your question, could you please share some of your code and what you have tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: So far we have just created the "POCO" classes from our existing DB using the EF core scaffold cmd. We have added the DBSet entries into the DBContext. There is nothing "new" that we have done. We were looking to get sample code from others that have setup DB first with ABP template. We also have a need to use SPs, would like to see some sample code for doing that too.

Comment: What are you actually stuck with?  Is there something that doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a .NET Core new project from any of the templates [listed](https://github.com/dotnet/templating/wiki/Available-templates-for-dotnet-new)

   `dotnet new mvc -au None -f netcoreapp1.0`
2. EF Core supports existing DB(DB First approach) and the details instructions are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db) .Basically you will be using the Scaffold-DbContext command to generate all the model classes.

Please note that **Scaffold-DbContext** does not support StoredProcedures yet and it is in the [works](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/245) .So that you may have to manage that differently

Comment: Thanks for reply! I actually found that MS doc myself just after I posted my thread. I have followed it step by step. But I keep running into another error during migration scaffold. I have posted that to aspnetzero forum for the support team.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can't use EF Code-First because your company doesn't want to lose your current database, data, SPs, etc. That's fine.

So, my advise is to create an ABP application and create your entities in such a way that they match your current relational model (database). This is right because EF is flexible enough to customize the generated relational model:

- relationships between tables
- table and column names
- primery key types
- foreign keys
- and so on.

In your **YourApp_DbContext** class you can override **OnModelCreating** and personalize the generated relational model.

Once your entities match with your relational model, you can go on with Code-First approach.

I think using Database-First approach is not right way and ABP isn't designed for that. Use Database-First approach just to initially generate your entities (to save time if you like).

About SPs, you can call SPs in EF. You can do raw SQL queries and the result can be mapped to entities or any other custom class.

I hope you find it useful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I appreciate it. The enterprise is an extremely large global org. We have separation of duties policies, as you would expect. We have data architects, DBA and then our team the app developers. Due to this structure, we are not permitted to use code first, as that falls on the DA and DBA teams. We as the app team are not permitted to create DB objects of any kind. We can only propose a design to the DA/DBA. I personally have worked with the ABP template for nearly year now using code-first for an independent project. I just wanted the code snippets for using ABP DB first.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Code First Migrations, but you can still take advantage of code first entity mappings. For existing database tables, use reverse engineering tools to create code first model of your database.

For stored procedures you can use Dapper (which is integrated with aspnetboilerplate [click here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Abp.Dapper)). On the other hand entity framework also supports stored procedures. You have to create custom repository > [click here for more info](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Repositories#custom-repositories).

This is a sample custom command executing. This way you can run sp.. [See here for more info](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/583)

```
using (var uow = uowManager.Begin(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))
{
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        con.Open();

        using (var command = new SqlCommand("select * from ... ", con))
        {
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    return reader.GetString(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    uow2.Complete();
}
```